# how to configure react-native expo apps to run in android Studio?

Tags: android-studio, react-native, expo

I have an react-native Expo project which i want to run in Android Studio to be able to debug it there.

So far, I installed everything, connected a device to laptop, but i am not running it in Android Studio.
I run the project with "npm start", scan QR code to install it to the device. As the result, I keep seeing "no debuggable process" in Android Monitor.

When I click "run" menu in Android Studio, it shows a "run" popup box and clicking which opens the "configuration" window.

I think I am missing something in configuration and not running the project using android studio, that is why I am not being able to debug it.
How do I configure it? I find no manual. Please help!

Comment: Was the project created with `create-react-native-app`? (https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app). You'll have to "eject" it to be able to run it on an actual Android device without Expo (https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/blob/master/EJECTING.md)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the project was created with [`create-react-native-app`](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/), you'll need to [eject](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app/blob/master/EJECTING.md) it, then you can run it with: `react-native run-android`. This will build the project just as if you were building it in Android studio.

Make sure you have `react-native-cli` installed globally for this to work. Once it is ejected, you can open the `android` folder in Android Studio and build it that way if you prefer.